# Semantic MediaWiki {{#ask}} - how to show source value instead "redirect name"?

Tags: mediawiki, semantics

I have a page(such as: Air Canada), in page, there is a property IATA, value is "AC".

Then, in Main_Page, I used:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Airline]]
| ?IATA
}}
```

to list. (#ask is a feature in Semantic mediawiki extension)
It can work OK.

But, if I created a redirect page(AC) to "Air Canada", then, the string "AC"(listed in Main_Page) will be changed to "Air Canada".

So, my question is how to disable this translator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound to me like you should use make the property `IATA` use the type text (add `[[Has type::Text]]` to the page Property:IATA. Otherwise the wiki will assume the type page, and unless you want to have specific pages about each IATA code, separate from the airline pages, that's not what you want.

And to answer you question: You can set `$smwgQEqualitySupport = SMW_EQ_NONE;` in LocalSettings.php to disable the functionality you are talking of, but doing so would be quite odd from a user's point of view, as redirects are basically a kind of aliases, and if the alias works in the MediaWiki world, you want it to work in the same way in the Semantic MediaWiki world.

Comment: thanks for reply, I created Property:IATA page, and add [[Has type::Text]] into. but, IATA column changed to blank in {{#ask}} list. And, in "Air Canada" page, string "AC"(IATA value) from a hyperlink to a pure text. Kindly, advise?

Comment: Properties are updated using the MediaWiki [job queue](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue), meaning that it can take some time for new values to appear. You can run the jobs in the job queue manually if you have shell access (`php maintainence/runJobs.php`). Normally jobs are executed when someone visits a page in the wiki. For low traffic wikis it can be a good idea to run a cron job to clear the job queue now and then-.

Comment: If, for some reason, properties fail to appear even when the job queue is empty, you can manually recreate all properties in the wiki (this is also a good idea to do after upgrading SMW). This can be done from Special:SMWAdmin

Comment: That's working! Now, IATA is "AC", but it lose hyperlink. I want IATA links to redirect page(that's why I create it) but is shown self-value(AC), can be resolved?

Comment: @FisherWei By making IATA a text property, rather than a page property, it will not link anywhere. It will simply be a text, in this case an airline code. When you create a redirect from AC to Air Canada, you tell SMW that AC is an alias of Air Canada. Therefore the page AC is now representing the airline (not the airline code).

I fail to see why you would want to link that text to a redirect page, but if that's really what you want, I would recommend that you use the [template format](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Template_format) to create such links. I hope that made sense!

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I will do deep think to confirm that should I need to show AC as text and hyperlink at same time. :) Thanks again.